QGIS plugin upload error: There were errors reading plugin package (please check also your plugin's metadata). Cannot find LICENSE in the plugin
My metadata text includes license=https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html and I have also included a license.txt file with the text of the license in the link above but still getting this error message:

There were errors reading plugin package (please check also your plugin's metadata). Cannot find LICENSE in the plugin package. This file is required, please consider adding it to the plugin package.

The zip file contents are- the plugin.py, init.py,plugin_dialog.py, plugin_dialog_base.ui,plugin_upload.py, resources.py and metadata.txt. I also added the license.txt file after recieving this error. It doesnt seem to work. I have uploaded other versions of my plugin and have not had any license errors before.

Since June 3rd the plugin archive has to include a LICENSE file. The file should have no extension and its all uppercase for the validation to pass. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Django/pull/410

Thank you for the response. My license.txt file had the text at  https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt - Now I changed the license.txt to LICENSE and I was able to upload the new version to QGIS plugin repository.

@CodeBard - please add your comment as answer.

Since June 3rd 2024 the plugin archive has to include a license file. The file naming should correspond to exactly LICENSE. Neither LICENSE.md nor LICENSE.txt fulfill the requirements for the plugin validation.
The change was introduced with following pull request: qgis/QGIS-Django#410
The upload validation does not enforce any specific requirements on the content of the license. However, for selecting an appropriate license, the following blog entry is a helpful resource: https://blog.qgis.org/2016/05/29/licensing-requirements-for-qgis-plugins/
